# CXF + Problem writing SAAJ model to stream

Tags: java, cxf

I trying to touch some service outside with CXF 3.0.0.
But got very strange behavior like sometimes it is working and sometimes it is failing with stacktrace attached (it can process multiple requests before failing). Request body is the same. Code for sending request is the same.

Any advice about this?

There are some logs attached. Left side with success, right with case when request was failed.

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Problem writing SAAJ model to stream: connect timed out
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:221)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:172)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:137)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.updatePurchaseRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.j.c.vc.mc.ICS.mCOP(ICS.java:814)
        at com.j.c.vc.mc.ICS.mCOP(ICS.java:81)
        at com.j.c.sru.PCU.updateProvider(PCU.java:164)
        at com.j.c.sru.PCU.updateControls(PCU.java:78)
        at com.j.c.sru.sruMessageReceiver.onMessage(sruMessageReceiver.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: connect timed out
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteStartTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:621)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.SimpleNsStreamWriter.writeStartOrEmpty(SimpleNsStreamWriter.java:265)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.writeStartElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:317)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.writeStartElement(StaxUtils.java:805)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:732)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:696)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:212)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:484)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:482)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:481)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:522)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1148)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:174)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1302)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1258)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:201)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:80)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.write(UTF8Writer.java:143)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flushBuffer(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1405)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.fastWriteRaw(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1451)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeStartTagStart(BufferingXmlWriter.java:791)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteStartTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:616)
        ... 42 more
```

Left - Success. Right - FAIL.

[image: IMG_2]
[image: IMG_1]

Comment: Check if you can resolve the hostname with the same IP address. Doing ping to hostname of the server.

Comment: @christmo we have multiple proxies on both sides so I have no IPs of servers. we are thinking about something like this, still investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Our request happens via proxy, these proxy servers are load balanced across multiple data centers. One of the data centers is not configured correctly, that’s why the connection cannot be established. Then our request gets timed out intermittently.